# Cache TreeSet for statistics

Tags: java, set

I need to Package 3000 different Carts, every Cart have taxes like 7%, 15% and/or 19%. I store the taxes in `Byte`, the `Packets` in `Packet`. If 1000 Packets have the same Taxes (7% and 19% in example), the Packet shall referee the Same Tax's Set (named `cartTaxes` in the code).

```
SortedSet<SortedSet<Byte>> cachedTaxes = new TreeSet();
Set<Packet> packets = new TreeSet<Packet>();
for (Cart cart: carts) {
    SortedSet<Byte> cartTaxes = new TreeSet(cart.getTaxesAllItems());
    Packet p = new Packet();

    // This line is bad because there are 3000 similar TreeSets:
    //    p.setTaxes(cartTaxes);

    // Instead i like to cache same taxes to same TreeSets

    // Insert if not exists....
    if (!cachedTaxes.contains(cartTaxes)){
       p.setTaxes(cartTaxes);
       // ... and cache for others!
       cachedTaxes.add(cartTaxes);
    } else {
       // Use already instanticated, cached, value
       p.setTaxes(cachedTaxes.get(cartTaxes)); <<-----ERROR: function get unknown.
    }
    packets.add(p);
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a Map to store values you can lookup.

```
Map<Tax, Tax> map = new HashMap<>();

Tax cachedTax = map.putIfAbsent(tax, t -> t);
p.setTaxes(cachedTax);
```

This uses Java 8's putIfAbsent, but you can do the same thing in Java 7, with more code.

If you are using Java 7 you can do

```
Map<Tax, Tax> map = new HashMap<>();

Tax cachedTax = map.get(tax);
if (cachedTax == null)
    map.put(tax, cachedTax = tax);
p.setTaxes(cachedTax);
```

Comment: Hashmap? I never have `null` values nor `null` keys.

Comment: @PeterRader what is your question or doubt?

Comment: Just think `Hashtable` would match better. Unfortunatelly its Java7.

Comment: @PeterRader Tree collections have O(log N) access time and Hash collections have O(1) amortized.  You should be using hash collections unless you actually need a sorted collection and it doesn't appear that you do.

Comment: @PeterRader Hashtable is generally slower than HashMap.

Comment: oh i realy need SortedSet because `7%,19%` is the same as `19%,7%` .

Comment: speed is not important, i expect only 6 different values max.

Comment: @PeterRader In that case replace `Tax` with `SortedSet<Byte>`  BTW I suggest not re-using any name for commonly used classes, this can be confusing.

Comment: @PeterRader never the less, I suggest only using a Sorted collection when you really mean to do so, e.g. your example with the tax codes may make sense though I suspect they don't need to be sorted either.

Comment: Could you change your answer to a list using `indexof` and `get`?

Comment: @PeterRader using a List would be more complicated and slower. Why do you want to use a list?

Comment: Some may not understand why i need a map. And use `get` to check the existence of a value is bad because `HashMap` can contains `null` values. But sorry, ill answer my own question.

Comment: @PeterRader List can also contain `null` as well, not that it matters at all.  You should be using a Map as it is designed for lookups and it is usually the  collection of choice for a cache.  This is the collection the JDK uses for caches.

Comment: @PeterRader I assume you know that TreeSet is actually built using a Tremap and HashSet is built using a HashMap.  I don't understand why you are trying to avoid using a collection which is the obvious choice and in fact you happen to already be using.

Comment: @PeterRader I am baffled as to why `int idx = list.indexOf(x); if (idx >= 0) list.get(idx);` is better than `Map.get(x)`. It is slower and more complictaed.

Comment: Who said a Map is the obvious collection for cache where `key=value`? I do not like to give other programmers the freedom to put a cache where `key!=value` destroy the process. `Map.get(x)` it is not that easy, anyway i only say that `idx>=0` is not a expected way to check existence: using `contains()` is better.

Comment: A list as a cache was a stupid idea of mine. A list can contains the same value multiple times. A set is better. Sorry for that.

Comment: @PeterRader A set makes more sense and all the builtin set are actually built on Map in reality.  The difference between Set and Map is that Map allows you to look up a previous value which is why it is better for a cache. A List for a cache is not a bad idea, just not as good as Map.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

```
Set<Packet> packets = new TreeSet<Packet>();
for (Cart cart: carts) {
    SortedSet<Byte> cartTaxes = new TreeSet(cart.getTaxesAllItems());
    Packet p = new Packet();
    p.setTaxes(cartTaxes);
    packets.add(p);
}
```

I understand that the caching is in the responsibility of the `Packet` itself. So id modified the setter.

```
private static final Set<SortedSet<Byte>> cache = new HashSet<SortedSet<Byte>>();
public synchronized void setTaxes(SortedSet<Byte> taxes) {
  if (!cache.contains(taxes)){
     cache.add(taxes);
  }
  for (SortedSet<Byte> cached : cache){
    if (cached.equals(taxes)) {
      this.taxes = cached;
      return; 
    }
  }
}
```